# What y=0 is also a solution for: $y' = y^{2}$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

By using integration, I can know that: $y=\frac{1}{-x+C}$ is a solution. But why  $y' = y^{2}$ is also a solution?

Comment: What is the derivative of $y = 0$? What is $0^2$?

Comment: What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you pick an infinetely large value for your constant the solution will approach zero.

Indeed this is also a solution to the problem since for y(x)=0, y'=0 and y²=0

Answer (score 0):

When you solve the equation using integration, at a certain point you have to divide by $y$ to get $y =$ something.  But you can do this only if $y \neq 0$. This is the reason why $0$ does not appear in the set of solutions $\{ \frac{1}{C-x} :C \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Comment: But it just means that y=0 may be a solution of the equation. How to verify that it is actually a solution?

Comment: It's a trivial solution! The derivative of $0$ is $0=0^2$.